# Android Framework : how to make a app uninstallable which is prebundled in the device?

Tags: android, android-source

I have an application which is pre-bundled in the device. By default, all the system applications are not uninstallable.
But I am trying to make the application uninstallable which is pre-bundled.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The reason system apps are "uninstallable" is because system partition in Android is read only (under normal operation).

If you want to bundle some app with an Android device but let user uninstall it later, you should put it in separate folder under system, not in system/app or system/priv-app

For example, you could use /system/vendor/extras.
Then, have another app install it on first boot.
This other app can be you Setup Wizard, or a small background app.

Comment: searched based on the answer , by defining in make file LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/system/vendor/extras ?